# Remove synced contacts from gmail?

Tags: sync, gmail, android

I have a lot of old contacts I wish to get rid of. When I sync my phone old contacts appear. How do I remove them?

Comment: Have you tried logging into GMAIL on a PC and removing them that way?

Comment: Log into your Google Account and manage your contact list.

Comment: This can accomplished on PC only, log in on PC then manage them from there.